# Source API in Spark 2.0+

Tags: apache-spark

I would like to write a data source using the spark source API. I found in the internet examples and documentations that were written on top of spark 1.X using RDD.

Is it still relevant for spark 2.0+?

Answer (score 1):

It is still relevant. RDD is a core data structure in Spark and it didn't change with Spark 2.0.